# check div present in iframe body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I appended a div into iframe body like this

```
$('.editable iframe').contents().find('body').append('<div id="newe"></div>')
```

and it worked.

after that, I checked if that div is present in that by using `$('#newe').length`, but it gives null value, when inspected the div is present in the body.

editable is the class name of div (iframe is inside a div).

also tried document.getElementById('newe')

Comment: you would have to find it in the iframe : `$('.editable iframe').contents().find('#newe')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#newe').length
```

Will search for elements with id in *current* document. To search the iframe you will need to use something like:

```
$('.editable iframe').contents().find('#newe')
```

You also need to use double quotes, or escape the single ones in:

```
.append('<div id='newe'></div>') // Bad

.append('<div id="newe"></div>') // OK
```

<kbd>[***Simple fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/G2Y4u/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks @user13500 is there any alternative method for that? it works., but in ma extension it is not working.

Comment: @suneeshtr: You manage to add the div, but not get it afterwards?

Comment: yup., is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: @suneeshtr: You are absolutely 100% sure it is added: as in you can visibly see it in the iframe?

Comment: @suneeshtr: And, what do you get in the console when you do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/G2Y4u/3/ ?